# unit testing spring integration workflows

Tags: spring-integration

I have few spring integration workflows that i need to test in order to make the code quality scanning tools satisfied with coverage. I can test the workflow in real sense by making the messages flow and necessary mocks as required but the scanning tool don't get it that its being tested as it needs those direct method calls from test method.

So i need to load my spring integration configuration files but i don't want it to kick off the process, just load the context so that i can pick beans and do necessary tests.

How can i do that.
To be specific i have a jdbc poller for each of these flows with a poller configured, is there a way to achieve that? I believe somehow i need to tell the poller not to kick off the polling task.
Also i don't want to create a big set of configuration files just for the test separately but want to use the actual files in junit tests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `auto-startup="false"` on all your endpoints.

You can use a property placeholder and use a different profile for test/production using `spring.profiles.active`.

```
auto-startup="${not.testing}"
```

Comment: Great, it works. I did not use spring profiles as i find it overkill for current need. I just added System.setProperty("not.test.mode", "true"); in my application statup class and  <systemPropertyVariables>
                <not.test.mode>false</not.test.mode>
            </systemPropertyVariables> to my maven plugin running tests and its working fine.